# How can I create an ad unit in flurry?

Tags: flurry

I am trying to create an ad unit in flurry. [Documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/gettingstarted/basicadunitsetup/) says:

> Follow these steps to create an ad unit:
>
> 1. Log in to Yahoo App Publishing at.
> 2. Navigate to the Monetization tab.
>      If you’re a first time user, you won’t have access to this tab until
>      you accept Terms of Service first.
> 3. Select Applications and Ad Units
>      from the left-hand navigation menu.
> 4. Click + New Ad Unit button.

When navigating to "Monetization tab" I get a message saying:

> Self Serve Accounts
>
> Effective January 2020, Flurry for Publishers
>   Network self service accounts will be shut down. Payments through
>   December 2019 activity will be processed and paid via PayPal per
>   agreement terms. If you have any questions about payment status, or
>   signing a new agreement as a managed partner, please reach out to
>   Gemini.Self.Service.Help@verizonmedia.com.

This message cannot be canceled or closed. I cannot even press the "back" button in the browser. 
I have tried using Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers.
So I cannot continue. How can I create an ad unit in flurry?

Answer (score 1):

With the end of Self-Serve Publishing, ad unit creation is now limited to Managed Publishers only, which you need to apply to become.

Comment: Isn't it open for everyone? If I apply will I get easily or is it reserved to just a few that you decide?